# How to get ClassTag for specialized types?

Tags: scala

```
scala> val i = (0, 0)
i: (Int, Int) = (0,0)

scala> i.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: (Int, Int)] = class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp

scala> def f[T: reflect.ClassTag](t: T) = implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[T]]
f: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]    

scala> f(i)
res1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[(Int, Int)] = scala.Tuple2
```

The implicit `ClassTag` argument is wrong. `scala.Tuple2` is not the class of `i`. The correct `ClassTag` would be for `scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp`.

This behavior is a problem for us, as we use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) for serialization. You give a `Class` argument to `readObject`. As we take it from the `ClassTag`, we give it the wrong class for specialized classes. We then read garbage.

Am I using `ClassTag` wrong? Or is this a bug in Scala 2.11.0?

Comment: We can use Kryo's `writeClassAndObject` to work around this at the cost of 1 byte per tuple. I'm interested in the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer would not be `scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp`. You are asking for the nominal (and erased!) type of `Tuple2[Int, Int]` at compile time, which is `Tuple2`. Note that `getClass` is a very different thing, it gets you the class of a runtime value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But how do I resolve the problem that the class of `i` does not match the ClassTag I get for `i`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Haha, I guess you got me there :).